# Interactive plotting in a loop with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I *simply* want to plot using matplotlib, via ipython, as my data comes in. I am opening ipython using the -pylab option. In the code below, the time.sleep(1) just acts as a place holder for the time it takes for my experiment to gather data. The code successfully clears the previously plotted data, and updates the figure with the new dataset. BUT, when I try and move the figure around the screen the figure becomes frozen, and does not update as the code runs (displays a 'not responding' caption in the figure's header). I'd like figure mobility, as there will eventually be multiple plots tracking the progress of the experiment. I'd like the option to switch between them without everything freezing up. Any suggestions? Running the with python 2.6, on a windows 7 box.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
for k in range(100):
    plt.cla()
    time.sleep(1)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.semilogy(np.random.rand(100))
    fig.canvas.draw()
    plt.draw()
```

Comment: try `plt.pause(1)` instead of sleep

Comment: Your code works perfectly well on my machine.

Comment: Further, the `fig.add_subplot` command in the loop is not necessary.